# untar a .tbz file (location: s3)

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, compression

There a lot of compressed .tbz in a particular s3 location and I don't want to download them and use **tar -xvjf "filename"** to unpack them and then upload to s3 location. Is there a way to directly unpack and store in s3 instead of download and upload

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no.

Amazon S3 is storage only, you can get and put objects into buckets, and you can change their name/location, but you cannot edit them in any way.

You can consider using AWS Lambda if you don't want to download to your local machine